# Adam converges while SGD does not improve at all

Tags: convergence, keras, stochastic-gradient-descent, embeddings, adam

I am trying to build a model based movie recommendation system with a neural network.
The architecture looks as follows:

```
    user_id_input = Input(shape=[1], name='user')
    movie_id_input = Input(shape=[1], name='movie')

    user_embedding = Embedding(output_dim=embedding, input_dim=num_users, input_length=1, name='user_embedding')(user_id_input)
    movie_embedding = Embedding(output_dim=embedding, input_dim=num_movies, input_length=1, name='movie_embedding')(movie_id_input)

    user_vecs = Reshape([embedding])(user_embedding)
    movie_vecs = Reshape([embedding])(movie_embedding)

    y = Dot(1, normalize=False)([user_vecs, movie_vecs])

    model = Model(inputs=[user_id_input, movie_id_input], outputs=y)
```

This model is taken from [this](https://medium.com/data-from-the-trenches/deep-beers-playing-with-deep-recommendation-engines-using-keras-part-1-1efc4779568f) blog post.

In the blog post the `Adam` optimizer is used to optimize the loss which also works well for my data (fast convergence after 3 epochs).
For an assignment I need to use the `SGD` optimizer because I want to use the `momentum` parameter as well.
However, if I use `SGD` the network does not improve its accuracy any more.

I did some research and I did not find any reason for a significant difference in the learning between those two optimizers.

Are the two optimizers that different that one of them can learn of the data perfectly while the other one is not working at all?